# getting onenote api for page versions

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

i am looking for an api interface from Onenote to track my work. So lets say i have a shared pages with my friends A and B. Three of us are able to make modification and edition.

One day A made one new page and 10 minutes later B came and modified it. Thus for this page, we have 2 versions, A and then B.

So my question is whether there is an existing api to get the metadata, such as modified time and author, of individual versions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, unfortunately. I encourage you to enter this item in our uservoice site.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: here we go. i like this kind of simple and straightforward answer.